# Unable to Install ubuntu onto a blank hard drive

Tags: system-installation, bios

I just built a pc and I am trying to install Ubuntu 14 onto it. I did the process in which you format the flash drive to be able to have Ubuntu 14 and install directly in BIOS.

BIOS is set up to boot from the flash drive. Every time I try to do the install process, it will randomly reboot itself onto the motherboard BIOS menu. This loop constantly occurs and the only way I can use Ubuntu is to put the option of trying but not installing. HELP!

Comment: Please edit your question with a bit more info, including operating system you are installing over, hardware model, dual-boot or single, etc.

Comment: What does install directly in BIOS mean? From what I'm reading, that sounds like you are trying to install ubuntu into a motherboard instead of a hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run the installer *after* choosing the "Try Ubuntu" option? After the system loads, on the desktop there should be an icon for the bootdisk installer. Use that to start the install process, then please update your question with progress, if any.